# Jface TreeViewer nodes Link with files

Tags: eclipse, sdk, jface, treeviewer

I writing an eclipse plugin to analyze files for some defects, I get the list of java files, their classes and methods in a jface tree view, I need to open the file in the editor when I double click on the file node of the tree view.

please help me with this.

thanks,
Shasinda

Answer (score 0):

You should either use a common navigator framework with corresponding filters that already has the link and open function built-in for Eclipse Resources, however, is much trickier to set up - see the blog post *series* starting with http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-1-what-im-going-to-do/

Alternatively, you could add a double click listener that opens an editor (or checks existing editors of the current workbenchpage) by looking the open editors. For the basic idea, see [the corresponding Eclipse FAQ entry](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_open_an_editor_programmatically?).

Answer (score 0):

Use [IDE.openEditor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/ide/IDE.html#openEditor%28org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage,%20org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile%29) to open the editor.